# How to pass string/integer value from js to c++?

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I am using Nodejs c++ addon in my nodejs project. JS calls a method defined in c++ with a string as the parameter. I couldn't get the string in c++. Below is my code in c++:

```
NAN_METHOD(DBNode::Test){
  printf("Hello\n");
  printf("%s\n", info[0]->ToString());
  printf("%d\n", info[1]->ToNumber());
}
```

Below is my js code:

```
const test = require('./build/Release/test.node');
test.test('ssss', 99);
```

Below is the output:

```
$ node demo.js 
Hello
?ڄ?C
-272643000
```

You can see from the above output that the string and integer values are not correctly printed. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let start from numbers. `ToNumber` returns value of type `Local<Number>`. It differs from regular C-like value what printf can digest.
First of all you need unwrap [Local](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.8/de/deb/classv8_1_1_local.html). It is v8 pointer-like utility class.
You can do it with overrided `*` operator. So `*(info[1]->ToNumber())` gives us v8 [Number](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.8/d9/d29/classv8_1_1_number.html) child of [Value](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.8/dc/d0a/classv8_1_1_value.html). But this is not the end of story. Now we can pull good-old `int` from it `(*(info[1]->ToNumber())).Int32Value()`. Or you can use the fact [Handle](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.8/d3/dd5/classv8_1_1_handle.html) ancestors override `->` operator too and write like `info[1]->ToNumber()->Int32Value()`.

String case is harder. V8 uses utf8 strings and you can use [String::Utf8Value](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.8/d4/d1b/classv8_1_1_string_1_1_utf8_value.html) utility class to get buffer of `char` from it. `*(String::Utf8Value(info[0]->ToString()))`

Usually you do not need it in v8 addons and I suggest you work with v8 objects(like Local, String, Number, etc) in your native code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked that the number works fine. Could you let me know how to get the string? I just want to get a string in native code which is from javascript. Where should I look? I don't want it to be very complicated.

Comment: @ZhaoYi I updated answer with code example for string

Answer (score 0):

below is the solution :--

```
NAN_METHOD(updateSignalValue) { 
    Nan::Utf8String lSignal(info[0]); 
    int len = lSignal.length(); 
    if (len <= 0) { 
        return Nan::ThrowTypeError("arg must be a non-empty string"); 
    } 
    std::cout << "\n hello lSignal value is :"<
```

Regards, Rakesh Kumar Jha